# Why does KeePassXC creates a socket file in tmp folder

Tags: sockets, keepass

Im new to Ubuntu. Just started to use KeePassXC and noticed when KeepPassXC is launched, it creates a .lock and .socket file in the tmp folder. Im trying to figure out what these files are, what they do and how I can view their content?

I did found this on the site [What are socket files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372725/what-are-socket-files)

But that didnt explain why an application as KeePassXC creates and what it does, with a socket file.

Answer (score 2):

These sockets are related to a cross platform solution for having a single instance of the application. This socket is not communicating with anything.
When another instance of KeePassXC is run, it first checks to see if it can create a socket. If it cannot, then it assumes there is already another running instance and sends a message to that instance through the socket. This message triggers the running instance to come to the foreground.